# Adding selected values to a string

Tags: c#, asp.net, loops, foreach

Consider this code:

```
foreach (ListItem item in lstViolations.Items)
{
    if (item.Selected)
    {
        messageBody += item.Value + Environment.NewLine;
    }
}
```

I am trying to iterate through each `ListItem` in `lstViolations`. However, only the first selected value is added to `messageBody` and I can't figure out why that is.

Also, adding `messageBody += "test"` prints only the first list item followed by `test`.

Comment: Did you enable multiple selection on the list box? `SelectionMode=Multiple"`

Comment: Trace it. Does the test return true more than once?

Comment: <facepalm> ... Thanks Icarus. It has been a LONG day.

Comment: +1 for using Environment.NewLine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:
If it is a ListView, then:

```
foreach(ListViewItem Item in lstViolations.SelectedItems)
       messageBody+= Item.Text + Environment.NewLine;
```

If it is a Listbox, then:

```
foreach(string Item in lstViolations.SelectedItems)
       messageBody+= Item + Environment.NewLine;
```

This will iterate only through the selected items.

**Edit:** Didn't looked at the tags. This will not work for ASP.NET !

Comment: that doesn't appear to be a valid option.

Comment: There is no `SelectedItems` property (-1).

Comment: You might want to see this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selecteditems.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.selecteditems.aspx

If you are using either of the list, the above could will work.

Comment: @DelegateX: As tagged this is ASP.NET not Winforms, [`ListBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listbox_properties) not ListView. A thing like `SelectedItems` does not exist in ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

Or even cleaner and easier.

```
messageBody = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, lstViolations.SelectedItems);
```

Comment: The same here, such a thing doesn't exist in ASP.NET.

Comment: ok.. messageBody = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, lstViolations.Items.Where(i => i.Selected).Select(i => i.Value))